# Install specific version of ruby with rvm

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-16.04

I followed [those](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04) steps to install rvm on ubuntu 16.04 now when I try to install specific ruby version (1.9.1) I have this error

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /home/igor/.rvm/log/1513069679_ruby-1.9.1-p431/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Error log says

```
 gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/curses.so curses.o -L. -L../.. -L.  
-rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
 1.9.1-p431/lib -L/home/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431/lib -lruby -
 lncurses -ltinfo  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p431/ext/curses'
 compiling dbm
 make[1]: Entering directory '/home/igor/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p431/ext/dbm'
 gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -
 I../.././ext/dbm -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -fPIC  -O2 -g -Wall -
 Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o dbm.o -c dbm.c
 gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/dbm.so dbm.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -
 rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
 1.9.1-p431/lib -L/home/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p431/lib -lruby -
 lgdbm_compat -lgdbm  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p431/ext/dbm'
 compiling digest
 make[1]: Entering directory '/home/igor/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-
 p431/ext/digest'
 gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -
 I../.././ext/digest -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -fPIC  -O2 -g -Wall -
 Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o digest.o -c digest.c
 mkdir -p ../../.ext/include/ruby
 mkdir -p ../../.ext/common/digest
 cp ../.././ext/digest/lib/digest.rb ../../.ext/common
 cp ../.././ext/digest/lib/digest/hmac.rb ../../.ext/common/digest
 cp ../.././ext/digest/digest.h ../../.ext/include/ruby
 cp: cannot create regular file '../../.ext/common/digest': File exists
 Makefile:163: recipe for target '../../.ext/common/digest/hmac.rb' failed
 make[1]: *** [../../.ext/common/digest/hmac.rb] Error 1
 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-
 p431/ext/digest'
 uncommon.mk:134: recipe for target 'mkmain.sh' failed
 make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
 ++ return 2
```

Can you please help me solve this?